# How to find the list of indices of NaN values of a given column of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe and I want to get the indices of NaN values in Column 'b'.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3 ], [ np.nan, 5, 6], [7, np.nan, 9], [7, np.nan, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Output:

```
[2,3]
```

How can I do this? I would like to get the indices as a list.

Comment: `df.index[df["b"].isna()]`?

Comment: Thank you Chris, it worked. I also added tolist() method at the end to get it as a list.